# Does python provide a synchronized buffer?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, buffer

I'm very familiar with Python queue.Queue. This is definitely the thing you want when you want to have a reliable stream between consumer and producer threads.
However, sometimes you have producers that are faster than consumers and are forced to drop data (as for live video frame capture, for example. We may typically want to buffer just the last one, or two frames).

Does Python provide an asynchronous buffer class, similar to `queue.Queue`?
It's not exactly obvious how to correctly implement one using `queue.Queue`.

I could, for example:

```
buf = queue.Queue(maxsize=3)
def produce(msg):
   if buf.full():
      buf.get(block=False)  # Make space
   buf.put(msg, block=False)

def consume():
   msg = buf.get(block=True)
   work(msg)
```

although I don't particularly like that produce is not a locked, queue-atomic operation. A consume may start between full and get, for example, and it would be (probably) broken for a multi-producer scenario.

Is there's an out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: I don't think Python has such a thing.  If it were me, I'd use an unlimited queue, have `produce()` just do a push, and put all the smarts into `consume()`/

Comment: Sadly, for image processing type-task, this would fill up the memory with images each time the consume has a hiccup (e.g. hitting a breakpoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in for this, but it appears straightforward enough to build your own buffer class that wraps a `Queue` and provides mutual exclusion between `.put()` and `.get()` with its own lock, and using a `Condition` variable to wake up would-be consumers whenever an item is added. Like so:

```
import threading

class SBuf:
    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        import queue
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.nonempty = threading.Condition()

    def get(self):
        with self.nonempty:
            while not self.q.qsize():
                self.nonempty.wait()
            assert self.q.qsize()
            return self.q.get()

    def put(self, v):
        with self.nonempty:
            while self.q.qsize() >= self.maxsize:
                 self.q.get()
            self.q.put(v)
            assert 0 < self.q.qsize() <= self.maxsize
            self.nonempty.notify_all()
```

BTW, I advise against trying to build this kind of logic out of raw locks. Of course it can be done, but `Condition` variables are very carefully designed to save you from universes of unintended race conditions. There's a learning curve for `Condition` variables, but one well worth climbing: they often make things easy instead of brain-busting. Indeed, Python's `threading` module uses them internally to implement all sort of things.

### An Alternative

In the above, we only invoke `queue.Queue` methods under the protection of our own lock, so there's really no need to use a thread-safe container - we're supplying all the thread safety already.

So it would be a bit leaner to use a simpler container. Happily, a `collections.deque` can be configured to discard all but the most recent `N` entries itself, but "at C speed". Like so:

```
class SBuf:
    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        import collections
        self.q = collections.deque(maxlen=maxsize)
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.nonempty = threading.Condition()

    def get(self):
        with self.nonempty:
            while not self.q:
                self.nonempty.wait()
            assert self.q
            return self.q.popleft()

    def put(self, v):
        with self.nonempty:
            self.q.append(v) # discards oldest, if needed
            assert 0 < len(self.q) <= self.maxsize
            self.nonempty.notify()
```

This also changed `.notify_all()` to `.notify()`. In this use case, either works correctly, but we're only adding one item so there's no *need* to notify more than one consumer. If there are multiple consumers waiting, `.notify_all()` will wake all of them up but only the first will find a non-empty queue. The others will see that it's empty, and just `.wait()` again.

Comment: "I advise against trying to build this kind of logic out of raw locks" - excellent advice.
For clarity (and because I think the Condition docs are a little unclear), does the `with self.nonempty` acquire the lock, or is the lock acquired at get `nonempty.wait`?). If the former, get blocks put (right?). If the latter, two gets may reach `assert self.q.qsize()` (?) One get may make the queue empty for the other and its assert may fail (the  while not self.q.qsize() may have been passed for both, with neither calling wait).

Comment: Oh ... `with self.nonempty` acquires the lock, but `nonempty.wait` (temporarily) releases it.
Makes sense.

Comment: Right! That's part of what makes the condition-vrbl protocol remarkably robust - it does the right things at the right times ;-) Inside the `with:` blocks, the mutual-exclusion lock is _always_ held, except while `.wait()` is waiting for `.notify_all()` to wake it up. So there are no races.

Comment: See new edit for a somewhat leaner implementation.

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering about that. I think it would assert without it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what either "it" refers to in "I think it would assert without it". Which assert would fail without what, specifically? None of the code here should ever fail an assert.

Comment: If you have an empty queue, two gets waiting, and put adds a single item, and called notify_all, one of the notified gets would consume the item, and the second would find an empty queue and fail its assert, right?
notify() (vs your original not notify_all()) -- not just leaner, but correct.

Comment: The protocol always _tests_ for the condition it's waiting for, while the lock is held - it never assumes the condition "is true" just because a notify wakes it up. In your scenario, only one of the two waiters at a time can get the lock. The first consumes the only queue entry, and releases the lock. The second (which was still blocked trying to acquire the lock) then comes out of its `.wait()`, and _loops back_ to test again. But the size is 0 now, so it executes `.wait()` again. It can't get out of that loop until `q` is non-empty, while the lock is held (so `.qsize()` is reliable).

Comment: Good point. I misread while for if. Thanks!

Comment: Part of the "learning curve" I alluded to. The docs explain what the `Condition` methods do, but not the pragmatics of how they're intended to be used. "Always test for the condition you're waiting for" is part of that. Then it becomes easy: `get()` always tests for "the queue isn't empty", which is obviously necessary and sufficient for removing an item. So long as all mutating methods play along by working only with the lock held, it doesn't matter at all to what other methods do, or when.

Answer (score 0):

Queue is already multiprocessing and multithreading safe, in that you can't write and read from the queue at the same time. However, you are correct that there's nothing stopping the queue from getting modified between the `full()` and `get` commands.

As such you can use a lock, which is how you can control thread access between multiple lines. The lock can only be acquired once, so if its currently locked, all other threads will wait until it has been released before they continue.

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

def produce(msg):
   lock.acquire()
   if buf.full():
      buf.get(block=False)  # Make space
   buf.put(msg, block=False)
   lock.release()

def consume():
   msg = None

   while !msg:
       lock.acquire()
       try:
           msg = buf.get(block=False)
       except queue.Empty:
           # buffer is empty, wait and try again
           sleep(0.01)
       lock.release()

   work(msg)
```

Comment: This will deadlock when produce is called during a consume/buf.get.
Probably on the first call.

Comment: Yes, just check that the buffer isn't empty before reading it. Or just don't block when you are reading it and later check that what you read isn't None

Comment: For me, the point of using Queue over locks is that you don't need to poll - just be woken up by the new data when it arrives.

Comment: Fair enough, but queue doesn't notify other threads when it has changed. Look into threading.condition for usage of notifying threads. Though it is still similar to locks, either way, one thread ends up waiting on another

Comment: Queue.not_empty is a Condition - it explicitly does notify other threads waiting at get?
Waiting (blocking) is what I want.

Comment: You have buf.get(block=False) in your solution. Its explicitly *not* blocking.

Comment: You don't need block to be true, you just keep trying until there is something in the queue ready to read.